# How long does it take this object to arrive at the point $M$? Assume that $|KL| =|LM|$.

Tags: trigonometry, physics

[image]

- How long does it take this object to arrive at the point $M$? Assume that $|KL| =|LM|$.

**Options:**

a)  $\frac{3}{2}\sqrt \frac{h}{g\sin^2\theta}$ b) $\frac{3}{2}\sqrt \frac{2h}{g\sin^2\theta}$ c) $\frac{3}{2}\sqrt \frac{2h}{g\cos^2\theta}$ d) $\frac{3}{2}\sqrt {2h} \sin \theta$ e) $\frac{3}{2}\sqrt {2h} \cos^2 \theta$

I'm out of my mind right now. It seems very complex to me, doesn't it? In fact, I've to be familiar with free-body diagram to solve this question easily. Can I take your professional helps?

Regards!

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: This is more suitable for physics section. Anyway, your problem is not well defined. Should we account for friction? What force is moving the object?

Comment: @Vasya That info wasn't given, this object is just getting released from $K$. Apparently, It wants us to give an expression.

Comment: Then it's impossible to solve. For example, depending on friction, the object may not move at all, that's why we can stand on a roof without falling down.

Comment: @Vasya no need to consider the friction if it wasn't given.

Comment: if there is no friction, acceleration from point $K$ to point $L$ will be $g\sin \theta$. From point $L$ to point $M$ the object will move with constant velocity. Can you solve it now?

Comment: Well, except that the object has a nonzero width and so its path is not precisely the surface that it travels along; at the bottom of the incline it will "cut the corner" so to speak. It's really not a well defined question.

Comment: @Vasya It helped me to think better now and why $g\sin \theta$, instead of $mg\sin\theta$. Still seems like I won't be able to solve it with this info.

Comment: The gravitational force points straight down, the force that moves the object will be projection of the gravitational force to the surface (slope). If you draw a picture, you'll see that the gravitational force is the hypotenuse and the projection is a leg opposite to angle which will be equal to $\theta$ (similar triangles)

Comment: @Displayed If the force on a body of mass $m$ is $mg\sin\theta$, what's the acceleration?

Comment: @Andrei we get $a = g\sin \theta$ for acceleration.

Comment: @Displayed:  You are not allowed to "pass through" exercises and claim "no need to consider the friction if it wasn't given."  You are know the one who asks Readers a Question, and it is up to you to give a fully detailed problem statement, together with the context of what you need help with.  Your Comments suggest you have a frictionless model, and that you know the acceleration of the object along the diagonal slope.  Please edit your Question to include these important facts.

Comment: @hardmath That info hadn't been given in the question, which means that no need to consider friction force. In particular, I can't give info about what I don't know or wasn't given, just writing the question as it is.

Comment: Again, when you post a question here, it is you that is asking.  We are not responding to questions from your instructor or your textbook, but we are here to help students from all levels of mathematics.  Don't mistake this as an invitation to have Math.SE Readers do your thinking for you.

Comment: @hardmath I'm too sorry again.

Comment: In d) and e)  $g$ not involved, so they are eliminated; $c)$ is eliminated because $ \theta $ gives finite time. We have to choose between a) and b) using the fact that effective $g$ is $ g \sin \theta $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Newton's equations of motion](http://www.mathsmutt.co.uk/files/newt.htm)

$mg\sinθ=ma$

$⇒a=g\sinθ$

$v^2=2g\sinθ*h/\sinθ$ (velocity on point L).

$v=g\sinθt_1$

$t_1=\dfrac{\sqrt{2gh}}{g\sinθ}$

$t=t_1+t_2=\dfrac{\sqrt{2gh}}{g\sinθ}+\dfrac{h}{\sqrt{2gh}\sinθ}
=\dfrac{3\sqrt h}{\sqrt{2g}\sinθ}$

this solution holds on difficult situation which square-like object continue to slide with vertex from point L.

Comment: Can you be more clear if necessary? And your final answer seems incorrect.

Comment: See the new edit, I uploaded the options.

Comment: I get the same answer. If you look carefully, it is answer b

Comment: @Andrei Oh, awesome! but I still couldn't get how to solve it.

Comment: @Displayed Notice $a=g\sinθ$ and $v_0=0$, just use three formulas of Newton.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki I've gotten $$\frac{3\sqrt{2}|LM|}{2\sqrt{gh}}$$ is it correct?

Comment: @Displayed It's correct.  You can check its unit. $\dfrac{LM}{\sqrt{gh}}=\dfrac {m}{\sqrt{m/s^2*m}}=s$.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki So is it same as the option b?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Is my answer which is $\frac{3\sqrt{2}|LM|}{2\sqrt{gh}}$ same as option b?

Comment: @ Yes, it's same, because $LM=\dfrac{h}{\sin\theta}$

Answer (score 0):

1)$ |KL|:=s.$

Note : $h/s= \sin \theta$; or

$s= h/(\sin \theta)$.

Constant $a=g \sin\theta$ down the slope.

A) Final speed at $L$:

$v_f = at$ , where $t$ is the time taken down the slope, and

$s= (1/2)at^2$, or

$t_1:= t =((2s)/a)^{1/2}$;  and

$v_f = a((2s)/a)^{1/2}$.

2) Constant speed $v_f$ along $|LM|=s$ ;

$t_2:= t= s/v_f.$

3) Total time taken from $K$ to $L$:

$T= t_1+t_2$.